# WatchService / dectect renames and or moves

Tags: java, java-7

Note: Replace INSERT/DELETE with the appropriate events from WatchService...

One more question regarding the WatchService class from Java7. How can I reliably detect renames (and maybe even moves) of directories/files? On a more thorough thought it seems very hard to even detect renames, or more precisely it involes a lot of state to keep track of. I don't think it's enough to check for INSERT/DELETE or DELETE/INSERT pairs of the same file/directory identifier. I think it's not enough to keep track of only one event. It might as well interfere with other DELETEs or INSERTs of files. Thus all I can think of is a really ugly heuristic to keep track of unique identifiers and to watch for an INSERT and a subsequent DELETE which might interfere with other events or DELETE/INSERT. Thus I think I would need some kind of timeout and after it expires just insert/delete all tracked changes. Definitely error prone or a best effort to detect renames :-( I think it's possible to get the relevant info from Linux and Windows (RENAME event), but I currently don't intend to use JNI, as I've already implemented everything with WatchService (even if I've spend only a few days).

Answer (score -1):

[StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardWatchEventKinds.html#ENTRY_MODIFY) is the event you are looking for.

Comment: I can guarantee you haven't tested this. On rename you get a Delete + Create event, not a Modify. You only get Modify for stuff like chmod...